# ng-repeat orderBy suddenly stopped sorting

Tags: angularjs

The data being shown in the ng-repeat is acquired from a firebase db and as such is loaded asynchronously

this is the HTML:

```
<tr ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}" ng-repeat="player in players|orderBy:'-Level'" class="neutral">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{player.PlayerName}}</td>
    <td>{{player.Wins}}</td>
    <td>{{player.Losses}}</td>
    <td>{{player.Level}}</td>
  </tr>
```

And this is my controller:

```
app.controller 'RankController', ($scope, angularFire) ->

  $scope.players;
  ref = new Firebase("https://steamduck.firebaseio.com/players")
  angularFire(ref, $scope, 'players')
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? why is the list not being ordered by Level?

*edit: Turns out this works perfectly if I use the model made by **lukpaw**. As such the problem must be in the data I receive which looks like this :*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the orderBy filter only knows how to sort an array. As such this would never work with JSON objects being used as the model.

I ended up implementing my own filter :

```
app.filter "orderObjectBy", ->
  (input, attribute) ->
    return input  unless angular.isObject(input)
    array = []
    for key of input
      array.push input[key ]
    array.sort (a, b) ->
      a = parseInt(a[attribute])
      b = parseInt(b[attribute])
      b - a
```

> ng-repeat="player in players | orderObjectBy:'Level'"

Answer (score 1):

I think that your sorting is OK.
I did simple example and it works in your way. Maybe something which did not you placed is wrong in your code (first check JavaScript console).

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table border="1">
      <tr ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}" ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy:'-Level'">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{player.PlayerName}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Wins}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Losses}}</td>
        <td>{{player.Level}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.players =
      [{PlayerName:'John', Wins: 12, Losses:10, Level: 2},
       {PlayerName:'Mary', Wins:7, Losses:19, Level: 1},
       {PlayerName:'Mike', Wins:5, Losses:21, Level: 1},
       {PlayerName:'Adam', Wins:9, Losses:35, Level: 3},
       {PlayerName:'Julie', Wins:10, Losses:29, Level: 2}]
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BjpQzv?p=preview)

Comment: it does indeed look like your example works just fine - which surprises me as the data structure is identical to my own(as far as i can see)

http://i.imgur.com/bIviCWZ.png

Answer (score 0):

How about ng-repeat="player in players|orderBy:Level:reverse"?

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @RonnieTroj answer, this filter reuses built-in orderBy filter and can handle both arrays and objects of any comparable type, not just integers:

```
app.filter 'orderCollectionBy', ['orderByFilter', (orderByFilter) ->
  (input, attribute, reverse) ->
    return unless angular.isObject input
    if not angular.isArray input
      input = (item for key, item of input)
    orderByFilter input, attribute, reverse
]
```